# Are there any cases where it is incorrect to replace push_back with emplace_back?

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, c++03

Can I break a valid C++03 program by replacing `std::vector::push_back` with `emplace_back` and compiling it with C++ 11 compiler? From reading `emplace_back` reference I gather it shouldn't happen, but I'll admit I don't fully get rvalue references.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I constructed a short example that actually fails to compile when `push_back` is replaced by `emplace_back`:

```
#include <vector>
struct S {
    S(double) {}
  private:
    explicit S(int) {}
};
int main() {
    std::vector<S>().push_back(0); // OK
    std::vector<S>().emplace_back(0); // error!
}
```

The call to `push_back` needs to convert its argument `0` from type `int` to type `S`. Since this is an implicit conversion, the explicit constructor `S::S(int)` is not considered, and `S::S(double)` is called. On the other hand, `emplace_back` performs direct initialization, so both `S::S(double)` and `S::S(int)` are considered. The latter is a better match, but it's `private`, so the program is ill-formed.

Comment: Indeed, clever. When I first looked at this question I thought to myself, "well, `emplace_back` can call explicit constructors". Then I foolishly thought, "but that's a breaking change when moving from `emplace_back` to `push_back`, not the other way around". You can do the same thing with a situation where the `emplace_back` call becomes ambiguous where `push_back` is not: `struct S { S(double) {} explicit S(float) {} };`, but of course that's a *terrible* set of constructors to give `S`.

Comment: So does that mean as long as the code can be successfully compiled, there's no worry to shift to emplace_back?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can change the behavior (more than just avoiding a copy constructor call), since `emplace_back` only sees imperfectly forwarded arguments.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

struct Arg { Arg( int ) {} };

struct S
{
    S( Arg ) { cout << "S(int)" << endl; }
    S( void* ) { cout << "S(void*)" << endl; }
};

auto main()
    -> int
{
    vector<S>().ADD( 0 );
}
```

Example builds:

```
[H:\dev\test\0011]
> g++ foo.cpp -D ADD=emplace_back && a
S(int)

[H:\dev\test\0011]
> g++ foo.cpp -D ADD=push_back && a
S(void*)

[H:\dev\test\0011]
> _
```

---

**Addendum**: as pointed out by Brian Bi in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22083198/464581), another difference that can lead to different behavior is that a `push_back` call involves an implicit conversion to `T`, which disregards `explicit` constructors and conversion operators, while `emplace_back` uses direct initialization, which does consider also `explicit` constructors and conversion operators.

Comment: Could you explain in more detail how this works? I tried to figure it out myself but I'm really intrigued.

Comment: @BrianBi: you can't have more than one user-defined conversion in a conversion sequence. So `null pointer constant` -> `void*` -> `S` is the only available conversion with `push_back`. With `emplace_back`, the fact that `0` is a null pointer constant is lost because the template parameter pack can't capture that, it just captures that it's an `int` (hence "imperfectly forwarded"). Furthermore there's no need for two user-defined conversions in one sequence because we're explicitly constructing an `S`. So the `Arg` constructor is selected for `S`, with an implicit conversion `int` -> `Arg`.

Comment: @SteveJessop: thanks, as it turned out i didn't 100% understand my own example code until i read your reply to Brian. :-)

Answer (score 2):

The `emplace` versions don't create an object of the desired type *at all* under exception circumstances.  This can lead to a bug.

Consider the following example, which uses `std::vector` for simplicity (assume `uptr` behaves like `std::unique_ptr`, except the constructor is not explicit):

```
std::vector<uptr<T>> vec;
vec.push_back(new T());
```

It is exception-safe.  A temporary `uptr<T>` is created to pass to `push_back`, which is moved into the vector.  If reallocation of the vector fails, the allocated `T` is still owned by a smart pointer which correctly deletes it.

Compare to:

```
std::vector<uptr<T>> vec;
vec.emplace_back(new T());
```

`emplace_back` is not allowed to create a temporary object.  The `ptr` will be created once, in-place in the vector.  If reallocation fails, there is no location for in-place creation, and no smart pointer will ever be created.  The `T` will be leaked.

Of course, the best alternative is:

```
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<T>> vec;
vec.push_back(make_unique<T>());
```

which is equivalent to the first, but makes the smart pointer creation explicit.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have crazy side-effects in copy constructor of the objects that you hold in your vector, then no.

`emplace_back` was introduced to optimise-out unnecessary copying and moving.

Comment: Also note that several of those optimizations were _also_ applied to `push_back`.

Comment: Yep, but compiler *has to be sure* that constructors are trivial, and by doing so it won't change overall result

Comment: I was thinking of capture by move, push_back is now move aware.  Not sure what you're thinking I meant.

Comment: I meant that compiler cannot substitute copy, that is done using push_back with move, unless there is no side-effect. Or am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: I _think_ this is just a communication error, and that we're in agreement.  I was merely observing that `push_back` now does less copying than it did in C++03 due to rvalues.

Comment: This answer is technically wrong (an example is given in my answer), but as a matter of practice you would have to be haunted by mr. Murphy in order for the code to be broken.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose a user-defined class could be initialized from braced-initializer. e.g.

```
struct S {
    int value;
};
```

then

```
std::vector<S> v;

v.push_back({0});    // fine
v.emplace_back({0}); // template type deduction fails
```

[`std::vector::emplace_back`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/emplace_back) is template function but [`std::vector::push_back`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/push_back) is non-template function. With a braced-initializer `std::vector::emplace_back` would fail because [template argument deduction](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_argument_deduction#Non-deduced_contexts) fails.

> Non-deduced contexts
>
> 6) The parameter P, whose A is a braced-init-list, but P is not `std::initializer_list` or a reference to one:

[LIVE](https://wandbox.org/permlink/vSSIjKCgkHgTYfPG)

Answer (score 0):

```
int main() {
std::vector<S>().push_back(0);
std::vector<S>().emplace_back(0); 
}
```

Give struct constructor in emplace_back i.e The above code will be like this

```
int main() {
std::vector<S>().push_back(0); 
std::vector<S>().emplace_back(S(0)); 
}
```