# Create a vector of shared_ptr to ints

Tags: c++, c++11, shared-ptr, smart-pointers

Attempting to create a vector of shared_ptr to int.

Where am I going wrong? Thanks. Keith :^)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <memory>

int main() {
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<int> > w;
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<int> >::iterator it_w;
    w.push_back(new int(7));

    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

Compiler result:

```
pickledegg> g++ -std=c++11 -o shared_ptr shared_ptr.cpp
shared_ptr.cpp:29:4: error: no matching member function for call to 'push_back'
        w.push_back(new int(7));
        ~~^~~~~~~~~
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/vector:697:36: note: 
      candidate function not viable: no known conversion from 'int *' to 'const value_type' (aka
      'const std::__1::shared_ptr<int>') for 1st argument
    _LIBCPP_INLINE_VISIBILITY void push_back(const_reference __x);
                                   ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/vector:699:36: note: 
      candidate function not viable: no known conversion from 'int *' to 'value_type' (aka
      'std::__1::shared_ptr<int>') for 1st argument
    _LIBCPP_INLINE_VISIBILITY void push_back(value_type&& __x);
                                   ^
1 error generated.
```

Comment: I may have a question. is shared_ptr<int> meaningful? Since sizeof(shared_ptr<int> ) is 8 and size of int is also 8. Then passing shared_ptr probably amounts to passing by value in terms of memory efficiency, right?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `std::shared_ptr<T>` constructor that accepts raw pointers is marked explicit. [source](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/shared_ptr). You will not be able to call `push_back` with a raw pointer, as it's not implicitly convertible to `std::shared_ptr<int>` which is what `push_back` takes as an argument. The solution is to either use `emplace_back` instead of `push_back` or to use `std::make_shared<int>`.

`emplace_back` matches the parameters given to one of T's constructors.

```
w.emplace_back(new int(7));
```

`std::make_shared<int>` returns an object of type `std::shared_ptr<int>`, avoiding this problem.

```
w.push_back(std::make_shared<int>(7));
```

You may combine these solutions.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <memory>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<int> > w;
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<int> >::iterator it_w;
    w.emplace_back(std::make_shared<int>(7));

    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

Edit: As an additional note, always prefer `std::make_shared<T>(...)` over `std::shared_ptr<T>(new T(...))`. It is designed to avoid very subtle potential memory leaks. It also elegantly avoids the situation where you have `new` without `delete` which may bother some people.

Edit 2: Additionally, `std::make_shared<T>(...)` has a performance  advantage where it avoids an additional allocation in `std::shared_ptr(new T(...))' [see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20895705/7359094).

Comment: "It also elegantly avoids the situation where you have `new` without `delete` which may bother some people" I find that it tends to bother static code analysis tools more often than people these days.

Comment: `emplace_back(std::make_shared<int>(7))` calls copy-ctor of `std::shared_ptr`, which is bit clupsy, because emplace_back is there for being able to get around that.

Comment: Are both 'make_shared' and 'emplace_back' necessary? Is ``w.push_back(std::make_shared<int>(7));`` acceptable?

Comment: Edit 3: for the ultra subtle: using `make_shared` has the downside that memory used for the actual object will not be reclaimed as long as any weak pointers are alive. But it's incredibly rare that this actually matters.

Comment: @kmiklas I believe both forms are equivalent in this case. There are other questions on SO that investigate more thoroughly the difference between the two methods ([like this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4303513/push-back-vs-emplace-back) and [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22080290/are-there-any-cases-where-it-is-incorrect-to-replace-push-back-with-emplace-back)).